# Beforeunload event is not getting the custom message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code :

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
  App.confirm('popup.cancel.confirmation.message', $('#confirm-import-modal'), true);
  return "Do you really want to close?";
});
```

I have 2 questions about this piece of code :

1. I have always the message `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.`, and I put the message `Do you really want to close?`
2. App.confirm show a popup, is possible to display only this popup whitout the confirm default popup from javascript ? Because now I have 2 popups, one default from javascript and another generate by App.confirm()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. This is by design. In most modern browsers you cannot modify the message that's displayed by the alert popped up by this event. 2. No. See #1

Comment: The ability to set a custom message was removed from most browsers a while back to combat scam sites manipulating tech-illiterate users.